# list the bookings using FileMaker PHP Api which has a bigger id than 152810

Tags: php, api, scripting, connection, filemaker

I am trying to list the latest bookings on my filemaker pro database. There are hundreds of bookings in the database. I just want to list the ones which has a bigger ID than 152810.

So, my table looks like in the screenshot below (The screenshot you see is made in excel not my output. I am trying to get the exact look as it is on the screenshot.)

[image]

```
include("filemaker.php"); 
$id = "152801"; 
$fm = new FileMaker('OpenBooking', 'myhost', 'admin','passw0rd'); 
$findCommand = $fm->newFindCommand("Bookings"); 
$findCommand->addFindCriterion("_kpnID",'>'.$id); 
$result = $findCommand->execute(); 
if (FileMaker::isError($result)) { 
    echo ($result->getMessage()); 
    return; 
} 
$records = $result->getRecords();
foreach ($records as $record => $id)  
$records->getField("_kfdTourDate");
```

I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getField() on a non-object in D:\XAMPP\htdocs...

If I use

```
$records = $result->getFirstRecord();
```

instead of

```
$records = $result->getRecords();
```

it lists the first row accurate.

First time I am using filemaker php api. I would appreciate any suggestion about how to display the rows as in the screenshot above.

Comment: can u please explain more that what u want?

Comment: Sorry, edited my original post. I am trying to list the latest bookings there are hundreds bookings on the database I just want to list the ones which has bigger ID than 152810. The screenshot you see is made in excel - not my output. I am trying to get the exact look as it is on the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that your "sales" layout is exists and then do a small change as flowing.

```
include("filemaker.php");
$id = "152810";
$fm = new FileMaker('mySales', 'myhost', 'admin','passw0rd');
$findCommand = $fm->newFindCommand("sales");
$findCommand->addFindCriterion("_kpnID",'>'.$id);
$result = $findCommand->execute();
if (FileMaker::isError($result)) {
    echo($result->getMessage());
    return;
}
$records = $result->getRecords(); 
foreach ($records as $record => $id)
```

Comment: thanks for that. I was looking to wrong layout. the bookings are in bookings layout. I edited my php file and my original post. Now I have just blank page. I don't get any error message. is there a way to print how many rows has been displayed so, I would know if anything has been found.

Comment: simply you can get count by php function `count($records )`

Comment: still blank page. I have updated my first post. Can you please look up again and see whats wrong?

Comment: can you please check once by updating a small `$id = 152810;`

Comment: gave ID 1528. it says waiting for localhost and the tab above the address bar keep turning arround.

Comment: One thing more to see that your host/ip `myhost` is right

Comment: yes it is because when I write a worng layout it says layout is missing but cannot list the rows. If I write this it works:  
    $record = $result->getFirstRecord();

    $date = $record->getField("_kfdTourDate");

    echo("We searched for $id and found cruise date to be $date");

Comment: I meant the connection works but still cannot list the latest bookings. but I can pull a data from a single booking number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132504/discussion-between-hijacker83-and-pradyut-manna).